# Confusion regarding present and past perfect

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Can you please tell which of the following two sentences are correct when the person has quit the job.

> How long have you worked at ABC company?

> How long had you worked at ABC company?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Only the second is valid if the person no longer works there. "...by the time you left?" is implied. You could also say "How long did you work there?"

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answer. How long have you worked at ABC company? implies the worker is still working, right? Is this question grammatically correct?

Comment: Note that the opposition is between the present perfect (_how long have you worked_) and the simple past (_how long did you work_). The past perfect has a special meaning that you are looking back on it from some later time in the past. So if the speaker has previously said "I left XYZ two years ago", then it would make sense, because the implied viewpoint is when they left XYZ. But in the absence of some reason to have a particular temporal viewpoint, it doesn't make sense and could be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kate said, "How long have you worked at ABC company" should be used if the person is *still* working there. "How long had you worked at ABC company" or "How long did you work at ABC company" are for after the person has left.

You could also say "How long have you been working at ABC company".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The question "How long have you been working at ABC company" is used when the person is still working, right? Can it also be used when the person has left or not?

Comment: Still working. I'm not actually sure what you would say for if you were unsure.